# Python Pandas Dataframe Conditional If, Elif, Else

Tags: python, if-statement, pandas, dataframe

In a Python Pandas `DataFrame`, I'm  trying to apply a specific label to a row if a 'Search terms' column contains any possible strings from a joined, pipe-delimited list.  How can I do conditional if, elif, else statements with Pandas?

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Search term': pd.Series(['awesomebrand inc', 'guy boots', 'ectoplasm'])})

brand_terms = ['awesomebrand', 'awesome brand']
footwear_terms = ['shoes', 'boots', 'sandals']

#Note: this does not work
if df['Search term'].str.contains('|'.join(brand_terms)):
  df['Label'] = 'Brand'
elif df['Search term'].str.contains('|'.join(footwear_terms)):
  df['Label'] = 'Footwear'
else:
  df['Label'] = '--'
```

Example desired output:

```
Search Term          Label
awesomebrand inc     Brand
guy boots            Footwear
ectoplasm            --
```

I've tried appending `.any()` to the ends of the `contains()` statements but it applies the `Brand` label to every row.

Most of the examples I come across are comparing if a column value `==` is equal to (not what I want) or are performing numeric comparisons, not text string comparisons.

Comment: `.str.contains()`? No need for the `.str` part

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, using `str.contains()` and `np.where()`

```
In [26]:
np.where(df['Search term'].str.contains('|'.join(brand_terms)),
        'Brand',
         np.where(df['Search term'].str.contains('|'.join(footwear_terms)),
             'Footwear',
             '--'))

Out[26]:
array(['Brand', 'Footwear', '--'],
      dtype='|S8')
```

Which you can assign to `df['Label']` like

```
In [27]: df['Label'] = np.where(df['Search term'].str.contains('|'.join(brand_terms)),
   ....:               'Brand',
   ....:               np.where(df['Search term'].str.contains('|'.join(footwear_terms)),
   ....:                       'Footwear',
   ....:                       '--'))

In [28]: df
Out[28]:
        Search term     Label
0  awesomebrand inc     Brand
1         guy boots  Footwear
2         ectoplasm        --
```

Comment: Nice!  This makes a lot of sense to me coming from the world of Excel and nested If statements.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: how do you go about the same task without having SettingWithCopyWarning thrown out?