# pandas: create column conditioned on row containing a string in list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 20 columns, and 3 of those columns (always the same) may contain one or more of these strings ["fraction", "fractional", "1/x", "one fifth"].

I want to add a new column that says whether or not each row is "fractional" (in other words, contains one of those words).  This column could have Y or N to indicate this.

I've tried to do it with `iterrows`, like so:

```python
list_of_fractional_widgets = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    fractional_keywords = ["fraction", "fractional", "1/x", "one fifth", "Fraction"]
    # use str to remove offending nan values
    xx = str(row["HeaderX"])
    yy = str(row["HeaderY"])
    zz = str(row["HeaderZ"])

    widget_data = [xx, yy, zz]

    for word in fractional_keywords:
        found = [True for x in widget_data if word in x]
        if len(found)>0:
            list_of_fractional_widgets.append('Y')
            break
    if len(found) ==0:
        list_of_fractional_widgets.append('N')

df['Fractional?'] = list_of_fractional_widgets
```

however, I'm trying to understand if there is a more `pandas` / `numpy` efficient way to do so. Something like:

```python
np.where(df['HeaderX'].str.contains(fractional_keywords?)), True)
```

as described in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30649713/python-pandas-dataframe-conditional-if-elif-else), but using a list and different headers.

Comment: Please provide a small set of sample data as text that we can copy and paste. Include the corresponding desired result. Check out the guide on [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/3620003).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a single pattern by joining all the words with `'|'`. Then we check the condition in each column separately using `Series.str.contains` and create a single mask using `np.logical_or.reduce`.

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

keywords = ["fraction", "fractional", "1/x", "one fifth", "Fraction"]
np.random.seed(45)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(keywords+list('abcdefghijklm'), (4,3)),
                  columns=['HeaderX', 'HeaderY', 'HeaderZ'])
```

#### Code

```
pat = '|'.join(keywords)

df['Fractional?'] = np.logical_or.reduce([df[col].str.contains(pat) 
                                          for col in ['HeaderX', 'HeaderY', 'HeaderZ']])
```

---

```
      HeaderX    HeaderY   HeaderZ  Fractional?
0           g  one fifth  fraction         True
1   one fifth   Fraction         k         True
2  fractional          j         d         True
3           j          d         h        False
```

---

As a bonus, `Series.str.contains` can accept a `case=False` argument to ignore case when matching so there is no need to separately specify both `'fraction'` and `'Fraction'` (or any arbitrary capitalization like `'FracTIOn'`).